# how does return and rewrite works?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

```
location /movies {
  return 301 nice.com
}
location /foo {
  rewrite /foo/(.*) /$1;
}
```

I am accessing http://localhost/foo/movies. What happens is url gets changed to http://localhost/foo/nice.com. I want to know why because Here is what I think.

when accessing http://localhost/foo/movies, it gets rewritten as http://localhost/movies internally. then it starts processing from top to bottom and finds /movies endpoint. when It finds, it has to redirect to nice.com website. but only last part changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` statement is probably being interpreted as a path relative to the original URI.

You need to use URL syntax to specify an external site, for example:

```
return 301 https://example.com/;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) for details.